# EmulationStation hot key buttons not registering

Tags: raspbian, emulation

I'm trying to set up my SNES usb controller to work with **EmulationStation**, which works just fine.

But I'm also trying to set up hotkey buttons to save, exit, load the games. which don't work.

Well they work, but the hotkey button doesn't do anything.

The problem is I'm supposed to press <kbd>SELECT</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd> to exit the emulator -- instead, pressing just <kbd>X</kbd> exits the emulator.

Here's my config file for the USB Gamepad

```
input_device = "USB Gamepad "
input_driver = "udev"
input_b_btn = "2"
input_y_btn = "3"
input_select_btn = "8"
input_start_btn = "9"
input_up_axis = "-1"
input_down_axis = "+1"
input_left_axis = "-0"
input_right_axis = "+0"
input_a_btn = "1"
input_x_btn = "0"
input_l_btn = "4"
input_r_btn = "5"
input_enable_hotkey_btn = "8" #This doesn't register.
input_exit_emulator_btn = "0"

#Commented out for testing.
#input_enable_hotkey_btn = "8"
#input_menu_toggle_btn = "1"
#input_enable_hotkey_btn = "8"
#input_save_state_btn = "0"
#input_enable_hotkey_btn = "8"
#input_load_state_btn = "2"
```

So again, why would the hot keys not be working?

Comment: The hot keys don't register? As the title states, eh?

Comment: @Bex ...is there something JR didn't state clearly? because this is a very understandable question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Forgot about this question. I fixed the problem. I was editing the button config for the games, not for emulator.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried doing a a RetroArch config for your controler first?

Here're some (optional) steps first:

```
sudo chown pi /opt/retropie/configs/all/retroarch.cfg
cd /opt/retropie/emulators/RetroArch/installdir/bin
```

And then the actual controller config (which will append the result to retroarch.cfg):

```
sudo ./retroarch-joyconfig -j 0 >> /opt/retropie/configs/all/retroarch.cfg
```

(the `-j 0` can be 0, 1 or 2).

After that open the `/opt/retropie/configs/all/retroarch.cfg` and append these two lines:

```
input_enable_hotkey_btn = "8" #put value from input_select_btn
input_exit_emulator_btn = "9" #put value from input_start_btn
```

That will make the Select + Start key combo exit the game.

Comment: I hope this works as I also have a hotkey problem

Answer (score 0):

does this combo work?

```
input_enable_hotkey_btn = 8
input_exit_emulator_btn = 9
```

What emulator are you using? Does it support hotkeys?

(I'm not 100%sure this matters, but try a new line before the input_enable_hotkey line)

Comment: I'm using EmulationStation with the RetroPie project. It says it supports hot keys (and they worked until the update 2.0) but i'll try that combo when I get home.

Comment: Maybe just try to reinstall the app.